# JRuby : How to specify java primitive array

Tags: jruby

How can I specify Java primitive array?

Java Object array type can be specified like

`['a'].to_java(:string).is_a? java.lang.String[]
-> true`

but I don't know how to pass Java primitive array class.

`[1].to_java(:byte).is_a? ???`

`` [1].to_java(:byte).is_a? byte[]
NameError: undefined local variable or method `byte' for main:Object ``

`[1].to_java(:byte).is_a? :'byte[]'
TypeError: class or module required`

`[1].to_java(:byte).is_a? java.lang.byte[]
ArgumentError: illegal package name component: byte`

What is a JRuby type of java primitive array type?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.

`[1].to_java(:byte).is_a?([].to_java(:byte).class)
-> true`